# Troubles with Positioning in CSS

Tags: html, css, mybb

so recently I had opened up my forum and am currently configuring the theme, but have ran into some trouble. On posts, there are stats displayed to the right, but they're too close together and display obscurely. After awhile of research such as positioning, containers, etc., I still haven't been able to find my answer, and still desperately need help. Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skYNU.png)

This is the CSS for the statistics:

```
    .post .post_author div.author_statistics {
         float: right;
         font-size: 11px;
         padding: 3px 10px 3px 5px;
         padding-left: 50px;
         color: #666;
         line-height: 1.3
    }
```

If you need any extra information, let me know and I can provide it. Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Here's a part of the HTML for the stats.

```
    <span style="font-size:13px;">
    <div align="center">
    <div class="float_left">Posts:</div> <div class="float_right"> 13</div><br>
    <div class="float_left">Threads:</div> <div class="float_right"> 1</div><br>
    <div class="float_left">Joined:</div> <div class="float_right"> Oct 2015</div>


    <br><div class="float_left">Reputation:</div> <div class="float_right">
    <a href="reputation.php?uid=2"><strong class="reputation_positive">2</strong></a>
    <!-- end: postbit_reputation_formatted_link --></div>
    <!-- end: postbit_reputation --></div>
    <!-- end: postbit_author_user -->
    </span>
```

Comment: please show full code

Comment: are you wanting them displayed horizontally? Or just spaced out more vertically?

Comment: @kfreeman04208 I would like for them to be displayed more horizontally, so probably about 5px to the left. Also, the full code is over 2,500 lines long, so I just left the HTML aspect of it. Thanks!

Comment: please provide the page link

Comment: @AdiNugroho http://reverence.io/showthread.php?tid=2 Here's an example of the thread I was using.

Comment: @nil I need an account to see that page

Comment: My bad, here's an account for you: test:stackoverflow

Comment: can you provide the CSS for the float_left & float_right class

Comment: I'm not sure why, but they made separate classes for "float: left;" and "float: right;".. Hopefully that answers your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
.post .post_author div.author_statistics {
     margin-right: 50px;
     float: right;
     font-size: 11px;
     padding: 3px 10px 3px 5px;
     padding-left: 50px;
     color: #666;
     line-height: 1.3;
}
```

You just need to increase or decrease the margin-right value

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing as I thought this theme is quite normal in every single forum I had joined.

But you may try this code:

```
.post .post_author div.author_statistics .float_left {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

To achive this: [image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it! I sadly can't upvote it yet as I need 15 reputation, but as soon as I achieve it I will!